# nohup and sed, redirecting stderr and stdout

Tags: bash, unix, sed, pipe, nohup

On my server `nohup sleep 1 > nohup.out &` gives no help message. Good.
Running the same command on my laptop, I get: `nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout`. Although the command still runs and completes correctly, I do not understand why there is a difference in the reporting of this message between my two machines. Fortunately, however, I can resolve this issue on my laptop by simply redirecting stderr and stdout to a file: `nohup sleep 1 &> nohup.out &`

So .... what I'm trying to do is implement a more useful command on my laptop:

The following works fine on my server and no message is reported:
`nohup ls -1 *.txt | sed -e "s%\(.*\)%/home/user/scripts/script.pl -find \1 %" | sh > nohup.out &`

This line of code "nohups" a piped list of files into sed, where they are run through `script.pl` consecutively and executed in shell. `script.pl` prints data to several files, and also prints some info to stdout. I capture this info by writing it to a file called `nohup.out`

Now when I run this one-liner on my laptop, I get `nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout`. This is expected (but for reasons unknown to me). But when I modify the line to redirect stderr and stdout:
`nohup ls -1 *.txt | sed -e "s%\(.*\)%/home/user/scripts/script.pl -find \1 %" | sh &> nohup.out &`

I still get the message `nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout`

How can I fix my one-liner so that it runs on my laptop without receiving a message displayed?

Comment: What system is your server running (OS and version)?  What about the laptop?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My laptop: Ubuntu 11.04. My server: CentOS release 5.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I this might work for you:

```
nohup ls -1 *.txt 2>/dev/null | .....
```

The reason being the `nohup` issues the warning message to `stderr`, so directing `stderr` to nowhere `2>/dev/null` ditches it.

Comment: Genius! Your solution works perfectly. I did try to write stderr to /dev/null, but didn't think to add it before the first pipe. I had only tried using it after the last pipe in my one-liner. Thanks!